# GMM estimation of the CAPM: why not include sample mean of the market excess return as a moment?

Tags: asset-pricing, capm, estimation, gmm

I am trying to wrap my head around GMM estimation of a single factor model such as the CAPM. I started by asking [How come the cross-sectional CAPM equation produces $N$ moment conditions (not $1$)?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/74509) and am now following it up. Equation $(12.23)$ in Cochrane ["Asset Pricing"](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691121376/asset-pricing) (2005) section 12.2 (p. 241) says the moments are
$$
g_T(b) = \begin{bmatrix} E(R^e_t-a-\beta f_t) \\ E[(R^e_t-a-\beta f_t)f_t] \\ E(R^e-\beta \lambda) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \tag{12.23}.
$$
where $R^e_t=(R^e_{1,t},\dots,R^e_{N,t})'$ is a vector of individual assets'  excess returns, $\beta=(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_N)'$ is a vector of betas, $f_t$ is factor's excess return and $\lambda=E(f)$ is the expected value of the factor's excess return. The first two rows correspond to time series regressions for $N$ assets (one regression per asset), so there are actually $2N$ conditions. If I understand correctly, the third row corresponds to a cross-sectional regression of time-averaged returns:
$$
E_T(R^{ei})=\beta_i' \lambda+\alpha_i, \quad i=1,2,\dots,N. \tag{12.10}
$$
($(12.10)$ is specified for potentially many factors, but $(12.23)$ considers the simple case of a single factor, so vector $\beta'$ turns into scalar $\beta$, and the same holds for $\lambda$.)

Since we are trying to estimate (among other things) the expected market excess return $\lambda$, an obvious approach would be to use the sample average of the market excess returns over the $T$ time periods. In a GMM, the corresponding moment condition would be $\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T (f_t-\lambda)=0$. In the notation of Cochrane, it would be $\color{blue}{E_T(f_t-\lambda)=0}$. Yet this is not what we see in the GMM estimator for the single-factor model in equation $(12.23)$.

What I would find intuitive is to have
$$
\tilde g_T(b) = \begin{bmatrix} E(R^e_t-a-\beta f_t) \\ E[(R^e_t-a-\beta f_t)f_t] \\ \color{blue}{E(f_t-\lambda)} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \color{blue}{0} \end{bmatrix} \tag{12.23'}
$$
or perhaps
$$
\tilde{\tilde g}_T(b) = \begin{bmatrix} E(R^e_t-a-\beta f_t) \\ [E(R^e_t-a-\beta f_t)f_t] \\ \color{red}{E(R^e-\beta \lambda)} \\ \color{blue}{E(f_t-\lambda)} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \color{red}{0} \\ \color{blue}{0} \end{bmatrix}. \tag{12.23''}
$$
Again, since we are interested in estimating $\lambda$ (among other things), is there a reason for excluding the obvious moment condition in blue from $(12.23)$? I do not have well developed intuition around GMM, but I think the blue condition is pretty informative about $\lambda$, probably more so than the red one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notation note: I like using bold letters for vectors.

The vector equation:
$$ \operatorname{E}[\mathbf{R}^e - \boldsymbol{\beta} \lambda] = \mathbf{0}$$

basically states that for all assets (or test assets), the expected return $\operatorname{E}[R^e_i ]$ of an asset is equal to its regression coefficient $\beta_i$ on the factor (i.e. quantity of risk) times the price of risk $\lambda$.

In the general case, the factor $f$ need not be a return (eg. $f$ is aggregate consumption from GDP numbers).

### Special case: $f$ itself is a return

Then your blue line isn't excluded! It's in the 3rd line of (12.23).

If $f$ is a return, then substituting into $\operatorname{E}[R_i^e - \beta_i \lambda] = 0$ gives your blue equation (because the beta of $f$ on itself is 1):

$$ \operatorname{E}[f - \lambda ] = 0$$

Comment: That is helpful! Does that mean if $f$ itself is a return, then the vector equation $ \operatorname{E}[\mathbf{R}^e - \boldsymbol{\beta} \lambda] = \mathbf{0}$ includes the scalar equation $\operatorname{E}[f - \lambda ] = 0$ as one of its components?

Comment: @RichardHardy Yeah, the $E[R^e−\beta \lambda]=0$ eqn. applies to returns so if $f$ is a return, it applies to it too!

If all the factors in a factor model are returns, then you can: (1) substitute expected return of a factor $\operatorname{E}[f]$ for the price of risk $\lambda$ associated with the factor (2) algebra works out such that a risk-based asset pricing model with factors that are returns will have alpha as the pricing error: hence 0 alpha is the same as the model explaining expected returns (if factor is something NOT a return like consumption, then alpha need not be zero).

Comment: Unfortunately, algebra does not work out for me! I am quite confused by treating alpha as pricing errors in $R^{ei}_t=\alpha_i+\beta_i f_t+\varepsilon^i_t$ and using that as a basis for the GRS test, hence my [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605427).

Comment: I suppose it makes a difference whether I include $f_t$ among the test assets or not. (By default, I was not thinking of including it. I am interested in pricing assets, not their sum, and I can always obtain the sum from the elements.) If I do, then indeed the blue equation is part of the third row of $(12.23)$. However, if I do not, then it is not. If that is so, excluding $f_t$ from test assets would allow us to estimate the price of risk without pushing it closer to the market's realized mean excess return. On the other hand, including $f_t$ would push it that way. Does that make sense?

Comment: However, I am not entirely convinced by my own argument. Including $f_t$ seems like adding a collinear data point, as the sum (the market's return) can be obtained from the individual elements (the assets' returns). So perhaps the estimate of $\lambda$ is pushed towards the market's realized mean excess return $E_T[f_t]=\bar f$ regardless.

Answer (score 1):

**A guess:** In the context of the book, we are probably not trying to estimate the market's excess return *per se*. When the theoretical quantities are replaced by their empirical counterparts in the GMM estimator specified in $(12.23)$, $\lambda$ probably gets replaced by the empirical mean of $f$. Thus, we do not need the additional row in blue; it would be superfluous.

Then we can use the first two rows ($2N$ conditions) for estimating $\beta$. The third row (another $N$ conditions) is used to test the CAPM; if the CAPM holds, the empirical deviations from equality in the third row should be small. If they are large, the CAPM is unlikely to hold.

Comment: Yeah, he's got a far more general framework in mind where there's some stochastic discount factor that explains asset prices and covariance with that stochastic discount factor gives a payoff $\lambda$. The CAPM is a specific theory of that form that makes the remarkably bold (and it turns out empirically false) assertion that the stochastic discount factor is just the market return.